# Hosting your own DDNS

Tags: dns-hosting

I need to setup DDNS Server in our premises. Please guide me how I can go ahead like any pre-requisites for this.

About DDNS: As you might be aware that Many broadband access do not have fixed IP address. DDNS allows the domain name data held in a name server to be updated in real time. Common use for this is in allowing an Internet domain name to be assigned to a computer with a varying (dynamic) IP address.

Regards
Samir

Comment: Samir. Please further explain what you want to do. More information.

Comment: Why can't you use an already existing service such as no-ip.com?

Comment: Plus we don't do step-by-step guides, we're a site for professional sysadmins, not lazy amateurs who haven't even done their homework.

Comment: We are the IP & Analog Camera distributor company. Many of our end customer do not have Static IP with them. They normally used free DDNS service provided by manufacturer. If we host our own DDNS serice & offer as a free Service along with Cameras then it will be value add service for us to promote product more aggressively in market.

Comment: I am not expecting step by step guide. But i need what are the pre-requisites for setting up DDNS service in my office.

Comment: It's not going to add much value if you need someone else to set it up. What are you going to do when you need to troubleshoot?

Comment: DDNS will be setup in my office. IP or Analog Camera users will use my DDNS service to view the Camera from the Internet (the Cameras which got installed at users office i.e. thoise users who do not have Static internet IP from SP)

Comment: There are plenty of guides on doing this (Google for them) -- If you need more info than they provide you're not up to the technical requirements of doing this: Tell your customers to use no-ip, dyndns,  or another commercial solution and save yourself the headaches.

Answer (score 2):

Are you expecting to use [RFC 2136](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS#RFC_2136_dynamic_DNS_update) as your update protocol, or some custom http based interface like no-ip/dyndns?  If RFC 2136 works for you then all you have to do is setup Bind and enable [dynamic updates](https://web.archive.org/web/20121104130032/http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/192-how-to-allow-dynamic-updates-with-bind).

Comment: Yes. RFC2136...Like DDNS will be setup in my office. Then IP or Analog Camera users will use my DDNS service to view the Camera from the Internet using registered host name from my DDNS server (to view the Cameras which got installed at users office). It will be beneficial for those users who do not have Static internet IP from SP

Comment: But how do i setup Bind & How do i enable dynamic updates

Comment: Did you click the link in the answer?